# How can work WinForm client with WCF session?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, session

I have a distribuited application with WinForm client connected to WCF services.
Currently I don't use the session.
I want tu use session, because application have a login, operations and logout.

In WCF side  I have this code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOperationsUser
{

    [OperationContract]
    User login(User loginUsers);

    *****
}
```

In client side I use this  way

```
private OperationsUser WCF_OPERATIONS_USER =  new OperationsUser ();
```

and so call methods

```
User userLogin = WCF_OPERATIONS_USER.login(myUser)
```

How can I use session for each user ?

Comment: My question more is different.

Comment: so, has my proposal solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a service with `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession`, so that will guarantee you having the same instance of service for serving subsequent requests.

2) to start new sessions use service operations marked with `OperationContract(IsInitiating = True)`

3) In one session one same instance of service will be used, so you can have a state in this service.

4) to close session use method marked with `OperationContract(IsTerminating = True)`

To both *IsInitiating*  and *IsTerminating* methods you can also add `IsOneWay=true`

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface Iservice
{
   // you do not need really to return anything
   [OperationContract(IsInitiating = True, IsOneWay=true)]
   void Login(UserData user)

   [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
   double ProcessData(double n1, double n2)

   // your implementation can do some finalization or even can be empty.
   // the call will simply drop the session
   [OperationContract(IsInitiating = False, IsTerminating =True, IsOneWay=True)]
   void Logout()
}
```